# Using stored sql table multiple times in a query

Tags: sql, database

Hello I have a sql query which generates rankings for my database

```
SET @rownum := 0; 

SELECT 
   rank, Total, UserID_ChampID 
FROM 
   (SELECT 
       @rownum := @rownum +1 AS rank, total, UserID_ChampID 
    FROM 
       Summoner_Champions 
    WHERE 
       Champion_ID = 0  
    ORDER BY 
       Total DESC) as result
```

This returns a correct table like

```
rank  total   userid_champid
  1     379     566_0
```

My question is: I want to update the table im drawing this data from

So I want to update is such that this code works

```
UPDATE Summoner_Champions 
SET Rank = result.rank 
WHERE Summoner_Champions.UserID_ChampID = result.UserID_ChampID
```

Sorry if this is a completly newbie question but I couldn't find a way to make that code work by using subqueries or work arounds

Comment: Which dbms? (Doesn't look like ANSI SQL...)

Comment: not quite sure what that means? im using phpmyadmin which i think is what u mean :)

Comment: Database product, could perhaps be SQL Server?

Comment: @jarlh := let me think of Oracle or postgresql using oracle syntax.

Comment: yes just a sql server, i just have a basic cpanel account, use php to run my sql once i know it works, use phpmyadmin to work on the sql before i put it inside of php files.

Comment: Taken from my phpmyadmin, Server: localhost via UNIX socket, Server Type: MySQL

Answer (score 0):

You can update your query using your `SELECT` query. See below:

```
SET @rownum := 0; 
UPDATE Summoner_Champions 
SET 
Rank = (SELECT rank FROM 
   (SELECT 
       @rownum := @rownum +1 AS rank, total, UserID_ChampID 
    FROM 
       Summoner_Champions 
    WHERE 
       Champion_ID = 0  
    ORDER BY 
       Total DESC) as result)
```

Comment: The subquery generated multiple rows, how do i let it update the rank according to the persons UserID_ChampID, the code in its current form doesnt work as the sub qry generates multiple rows. :(

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do:

```
UPDATE Summoner_Champions 
SET Rank = result.rank
FROM Summoner_Champions sc LEFT INNER JOIN (your Statement for Result) result
WHERE Summoner_Champions.UserID_ChampID = result.UserID_ChampID
```

EDIT:
2nd Approach, see my last comment:

```
UPDATE Summoner_Champions 
SET Rank = (@rownum + 1)
WHERE Champion_ID = 0
```

Comment: I tried to do as you said but i couln't simply inject my code inside the brackets and have it work, so i tried to work around it but cant seem to get it to work. I tried something like this (code)

Comment: Ok, could you send which code you tried, and probably create a schema at sqlfiddle.com? Plus which error you got.

Comment: never used that before, give me a sec to use it :)

Comment: keep getting an error when trying to create tables for the schema. Unknown Error Occurred: a timeout occurred on a exclusive lock with name [cfadmin] after 30 seconds. Link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2581/1

Comment: watched at your statement a bit closer, your trying to create a resultset from a table and use it to update the same table? why are you doing this?

Comment: Im not exactly sure what u mean, i have a list of rows with about 3k rows, each one corisponds to a person and there score, every set amount of time i want to run a cron job, which executes an sql script which updates the rankings of the players, as there scores change constantly, but eventually there will be millions of rows so i cant just run the query whenever anyone wants it. Ur 2nd approach to update summoner champions and set rank = @rownum +1 leaves out how im meant to reference whose rank its changing :(?

Comment: Ok so PLZ Show Schema and explain what comeout you would expect

Comment: Okay. Schema + Sample data here: http://imgur.com/a/YtLt3                            The expected result is that it changes the ranks from 0, to the actual ranking based on the Total. For instance lets say there is three rows, each sharing the same champ_id (0). Totals are 100, 66, 33. Then it would update rankings to be 1, 2, 3 for those rows :)

Comment: I Figured it out, your second approach was basically correct except it needed to be ordered by total Desc to get the correct ranks. Thank you :)

Comment: ok, I was wondering why it didn't work, because your having rownum as variable. If you want to have it absolutly accurate you have to skip rownum+1 and just set rownum, if the total of the current row is equal to the total of the preceding row. Plz. mark my answer as correct. thx.